# Зачем в Python 3.3 ввели list.copy() если можно использовать слайс без указания границ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, списки

Сейчас плотно изучаю нюансы методов встроенных типов, и есть один вопрос, на который не могу найти ответ.

В Python 3.3 ввели метод списка copy(), который делает поверхностную копию.
Но то же самое можно было делать, просто взяв срез без границ - list[:]

Зачем было вводить новый метод?

Подозреваю, что какая-то причина есть. Например, сначала я считал таким же ненужным нововведением метод list.clear(), введённый в том же Python 3.3, ведь есть же list = []

А потом я прочитал, что эти две синтаксические конструкции по разному работают в ситуациях, когда на список ссылаются две или более переменных.

Подозреваю, что и для copy() существует такое же очевидное задним числом обоснование, но найти его пока не смог.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чтобы сделать операции `del list_[:]` и `shallow_copy = list_[:]` более очевидными (discoverable) и читаемыми  для новичков (`list_.clear()` и `shallow_copy = list_.copy()` соответственно). See [Add list.clear() and list.copy()](http://bugs.python.org/issue10516)

В целом, в Питоне есть предпочтение к использованию слов вместо пунктуации, например: `and`, `or` вместо `&&`, `||` или `on_true if cond else on_false` вместо `cond  ? on_true : on_false` или `re.search(regex)` вместо `/regex/`.

Дополнительно, наличие явного метода `list_.clear()` может уменьшить вероятность возможной ошибки:`list_ = []` существенно отличается от `del list_[:]` (первая конструкция создаёт *новый список* и привязывает его к имени `list_`, вторая конструкция удаляет все элементы из *существующего объекта* (изменяемой последовательности такой как список наиболее вероятно)).

Недостаток, что эти методы дублируют функциональность изменяемых последовательностей/отображений (объекты с `__getitem__`, `__delitem__` методами).